# Why is my java code not limiting these numbers?

Tags: java, youtube

Currently having an issue with the amount of ticks that are being produced by my code. I am currently following along a video game guide and the amount of ticks that are used to update the logic is exponentially higher than the frames when they should both be resting upon 60. This is the YouTube video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VE7ezYCTPe4&t=1358s
any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advanced!

```
package game;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final int WIDTH = 160;
public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;
public static final int SCALE = 3;
public static final String NAME = "Game";

private JFrame frame;

public boolean running = false;

public game() {
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));

    frame = new JFrame(NAME);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    frame.add(this,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public synchronized void start() {
    running = true;
    new Thread(this).start();

}

public synchronized void stop() {
    running = false;

}

public void run() {
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double nsPerTick = 1000000000 / 60D;

    int ticks = 0;
    int frames = 0;

    long lastTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double delta = 0;

    while (running) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTimer) / nsPerTick;
        lastTime = now;
        boolean shouldRender = false;

        while(delta >= 1){
            ticks++;
            tick();
            render();
            delta -= 1;
            shouldRender = true;
        }

        if (shouldRender) {
            frames++;
            render();
            }

        try {
        Thread.sleep(2);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimer >= 1000){
            lastTimer += 1000;
            System.out.println(ticks + " ticks, " + frames + " frames");
            frames = 0;
            ticks = 0;
        }
    }


}

public void tick() {
    //updates the logic of the game.

}

public void render() {
    //prints out what the logic says to print out
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new game().start();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your `while(delta >= 1){` loop, you actually increment the tick. That delta should be about 16666667ns, given a perfect system, so you potentially have 16666667 ticks per delta. I'm very curious about your tutorial, because generally you'd use a delta in systems (like physics) and not in a loop. A tick is supposed to be one game loop, and the delta is used for physics calculations, etc. If you want resources about Java game development, I'd highly recommend checking out https://www.lwjgl.org/, not to mention plenty of articles on blogs all over about the topic.